# Why typing on object literal vs variable are enforced differently?

Tags: typescript

I think I saw something somewhere about this, but I cannot find it anymore.

I would like to understand why TypeScript typing is applied/enforced differently between object literal and variables.

```
interface User {
    id: number;
}

function p(u: User) { }

const u1 = { id: 123 }

const u2 = { id: 124, foo: 'bar' };

p(u1); // << Works as expected

p({ id: 124, foo: 'bar' }); // << ERROR as expected:  ' Object literal may only specify known properties'

p(u2); // << NO ERROR??

// workaround
const u3: User = { id: 124, foo: 'bar' }; // << ERROR as expected
```

The workaround is ok, but the asymmetry can lead to unexpected behavior where the developer has a strict Partial check to realize that other properties were allowed.

I am sure there is a reason for it, and I would love to know the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a part from the handbook which talks about this.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) To summarize the best I can: the reason why object literals are checked for excess properties (and not "passed around" objects) is because an excess property there is usually the result of a typo or other sort of mistake when working with something like an options object, which is a very common pattern.

I'm not sure I fully agree with this reasoning myself, but it is what it is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Yes, I do not like asymmetric rules and this one is no exception, but it is the way it is. Interestingly, they even confess it is "surprising" >> 'One final way to get around these checks, which might be a bit surprising, is to assign the object to another variable: Since squareOptions won’t undergo excess property checks, the compiler won’t give you an error."